# Macro redefinitions with header units

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2022, c++-modules

I'm experimenting with header units. Currently, I'm testing in Visual Studio 2022(Version 17.2.3).

I'm currently importing multiple header units, for example

```
import <windows.h>;
import <thread>;
```

**warning** `warning C4005: '__analysis_assume': macro redefinition 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\shared\specstrings_strict.h(933): message : see previous definition of '__analysis_assume'`

It kind of make senses because if `<thread>` and `<windows.h>` have any shared headers normally the inclusion guards or pragma once would prevent them from being included and being multiply defined.

I'm not really sure how header units can work if they shared header files with macros which a majority of header files of external libraries use.

I'm sure I can ignore the warning but I'm curious if anyone else has a better solution.

Comment: Sorry - My bad.

Comment: @coderdave Do you _have_ to use modules? Can't you just `#include <Windows.h>` and `#include <thread>` ?

Comment: Compile times with those 2 includes are 2.7 seconds and compile times with import are .23 milliseconds for a 12x speed-up.

I don't have to use modules but it seems if I want to keep a fast code base then it makes sense to move in that direction.

Comment: I see, but are you using the correct names? MSDN states `import std.threading;` to get the module including the threading headers etc.

Comment: import std.threading comes with other issues (e.g. `warning C5050: Possible incompatible environment while importing module 'std.threading': _DEBUG is defined in current command line and not in module command line`). Also, this is a problem with shared headers in general. If I swap thread with `import <cassert>` I'll get the same issue.

Comment: Oh, one would think that they would provide a debug compiled version along with the release version. :-/

Comment: Yah, @TedLyngmo its a fickle system and to import a module you need the exact same compile options (exceptions on vs off, etc...). I'm not sure how that would work without compiling std.thread for your project yourself. To be honest, I'm not sure how well thought out any of this is haha :)

Comment: FYI, you don't need to terminate a `#include` with a semicolon.

Comment: If you just want compilation speedup, did you try putting those in a PCH?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews FYI, that's not an `#include`

Comment: @holyblackcat header units can be selectively imported with a reduction in size compared to pch for faster compilation times. Additionally it’s easier to manage dependencies rather then a large mono pch

Comment: Do they `#define` it to the same value?  That’s not supposed to elicit a diagnostic.

Comment: @DavisHerring That is a good question. I tested a simple app with a common header that has a macro in it and two header files I imported and couldn't reproduce this error. I'm not sure how I track down if the defines are the same. Outputting the pre-processed file shows blank output when using the macro so it looks like they both define to nothing when only importing one header at a time.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is a known issue with import causing multiple macro redefinitions when using windows.h.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/warning-C4005:-Outptr:-macro-redefinit/1546919

We will have to wait for Microsoft to address this issue.